# Stochastic Gradient Descent Training Error

Tags: lua, deep-learning, torch, conv-neural-network

I am using a fully convolution network. My images are of size 512x512. Here is my dataset formation code.

```
require 'image'
require 'nn
npy4th = require 'npy4th'

function scandir(directory)
    local i, t, popen = 0, {}, io.popen
    local pfile = popen('ls -a "'..directory..'"')
    for filename in pfile:lines() do
        i = i + 1
        t[i] = filename
    end
    pfile:close()
    return t
end

dataset={}

path1='/home/dataset/train/data/'

path2='/home/dataset/train/label/'

x=scandir(path1)
table.remove(x,1)
table.remove(x,1)

y=scandir(path2)
table.remove(y,1)
table.remove(y,1)

num_files=0
for _ in pairs(x) do 
    num_files= num_files + 1 
end

num_files=2
--dataset of form input, output creation
function dataset:size() return num_files end

for i=1, dataset:size() do
    data=npy4th.loadnpy(path1..x[i])
    label=npy4th.loadnpy(path2..y[i])
    output=torch.Tensor(8,data:size(1),data:size(2)):zero()
    output[1][label:eq(1)]=1 --healthy
    output[2][label:eq(2)]=2 --emphysema
    output[3][label:eq(3)]=3 --GGO                                                    
    output[4][label:eq(4)]=4 --fibrosis
    output[4][label:eq(14)]=4 --early_fibrosis
    output[5][label:eq(5)]=5 --micronodules
    output[6][label:eq(6)]=6 --consolidation
    output[7][label:eq(8)]=7 --reticulation
    output[8][label:eq(11)]=8 --peripheral_micronodules
    input=torch.reshape(data,1,data:size(1),data:size(2))
    dataset[i]={input:double(),output};
end
```

I am implementing a fully convolution network in Torch 7 as below:

```
unet = nn.Sequential()
-- ndim=input:size(2)
ndim=512
unet:add(nn.SpatialReflectionPadding(1+ndim/2,1+ndim/2,1+ndim/2,1+ndim/2)) --reflection padding 
unet:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(1, 64, 3, 3)) 
unet:add(nn.SpatialReflectionPadding(1,1,1,1)) --reflection padding 
unet:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(64, 64, 3, 3)) 
unet:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2,2,2,2))    

unet:add(nn.SpatialReflectionPadding(1,1,1,1)) --reflection padding 
unet:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(64, 128, 3, 3)) 
unet:add(nn.SpatialReflectionPadding(1,1,1,1)) --reflection padding 
unet:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(128,128, 3, 3)) 
unet:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2,2,2,2))  

unet:add(nn.SpatialReflectionPadding(1,1,1,1)) --reflection padding 
unet:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(128, 256, 3, 3)) 
unet:add(nn.SpatialReflectionPadding(1,1,1,1)) --reflection padding 
unet:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(256, 256, 3, 3)) 
unet:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2,2,2,2))

unet:add(nn.SpatialReflectionPadding(1,1,1,1)) --reflection padding 
unet:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(256, 512, 3, 3)) 
unet:add(nn.SpatialReflectionPadding(1,1,1,1)) --reflection padding 
unet:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(512, 512, 3, 3)) 
unet:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2,2,2,2))  

unet:add(nn.SpatialReflectionPadding(1,1,1,1)) --reflection padding 
unet:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(512, 1024, 3, 3)) 
unet:add(nn.SpatialReflectionPadding(1,1,1,1)) --reflection padding 
unet:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(1024, 1024, 3, 3)) 
unet:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2,2,2,2))  

unet:add(nn.SpatialFullConvolution(1024, 1024, 2, 2, 2, 2)) -- up convolve 
unet:add(nn.SpatialReflectionPadding(1,1,1,1)) --reflection padding 
unet:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(1024, 512, 3, 3)) 
unet:add(nn.SpatialReflectionPadding(1,1,1,1)) --reflection padding 
unet:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(512, 512, 3, 3)) 

unet:add(nn.SpatialFullConvolution(512, 512, 2, 2, 2, 2))   -- up convolve 
unet:add(nn.SpatialReflectionPadding(1,1,1,1)) --reflection padding 
unet:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(512, 256, 3, 3)) 
unet:add(nn.SpatialReflectionPadding(1,1,1,1)) --reflection padding 
unet:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(256, 256, 3, 3)) 

unet:add(nn.SpatialFullConvolution(256, 256, 2, 2, 2, 2))   -- up convolve
unet:add(nn.SpatialReflectionPadding(1,1,1,1)) --reflection padding 
unet:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(256, 128, 3, 3)) 
unet:add(nn.SpatialReflectionPadding(1,1,1,1)) --reflection padding 
unet:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(128, 128, 3, 3))

unet:add(nn.SpatialFullConvolution(128, 128, 2, 2, 2, 2))   -- up convolve 
unet:add(nn.SpatialReflectionPadding(1,1,1,1)) --reflection padding 
unet:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(128, 64, 3, 3)) 
unet:add(nn.SpatialReflectionPadding(1,1,1,1)) --reflection padding 
unet:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(64, 64, 3, 3))  
unet:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(64, 8, 1, 1))  --output size
```

Below is how I am training it:

```
criterion=nn.CrossEntropyCriterion()
trainer=nn.StochasticGradient(unet,criterion)
trainer.learningRate = 0.01
trainer:train(dataset)
```

On training I get the following error:

```
# StochasticGradient: training  
/home/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/THNN.lua:109: bad argument #2 to 'v' (vector or matrix expected at /home/SparseConvolution/nn/lib/THNN/generic/LogSoftMax.c:26)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'v'
    /home/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/THNN.lua:109: in function 'LogSoftMax_updateOutput'
    ...e/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/LogSoftMax.lua:4: in function 'updateOutput'
    ...torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/CrossEntropyCriterion.lua:12: in function 'forward'
    ...le/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/StochasticGradient.lua:35: in function 'train'
    [string "_RESULT={trainer:train(dataset)}"]:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    /home/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:651: in function 'repl'
    ...me/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:199: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00406670
```

This is the first I am using Torch, can someone help me what I am missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The criterion you are using `CrossEntropyCriterion()` combines the modules `LogSoftMax` and `ClassNLLCriterion`. The function `yourModel:forward()` returns a matrix of size 64*8 and this criterion (`ClassNLLCriterion`), in particular, only accepts a 1D Tensor: [CrossEntropyCriterion](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/criterion.md#nn.CrossEntropyCriterion)

Comment: The size of the prediction using the forward function is 512x512x8.

Comment: I have 8 classes for each image pixel. Thanks, I got it.